# Changing value in Map dose not change actual value in dart

Tags: dictionary, dart

In the fallowing code example, I created a class that maintains a Map with some values.
The class has a "clear" method to clear the values in the map.
However, calling the clear method dose not clear the actual values on the map.

Any ideas?

```
class CountStuff {
  Map<String, int> Records = Map();

  CountStuff() {
    Records['one'] = 10;
    Records['two'] = 20;
    Records['seven'] = 255;
    Records['moses'] = 349;
  }

  void clear() {
    Records.forEach((key, value) {
      value = 0;
    });
  }
}

void main() {
  CountStuff cs = CountStuff();

  cs.Records.forEach((key, value) {
    print(value);
  });

  cs.clear();

  cs.Records.forEach((key, value) {
    print(value);
  });
}
```

output is:
flutter: 10

flutter: 20

flutter: 255

flutter: 349

flutter: 10

flutter: 20

flutter: 255

flutter: 349

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a foreach loop you do not modify the actual map, because you are working with a copy of the map values. It's not a reference or something.
So this code:

```
Records.forEach((key, value) {
      value = 0;
    });
```

really does nothing. You need something like this:

```
Records.forEach((key, value) {
  Records[key] = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your clear() function should look like this:

```
void clear() {
    Records.updateAll((key, value) => 0);
}
```

updateAll iterates through all map keys and updates values accordingly.

The accepted answer also works but it performs more than double work to find again the element by key although the element is already known by iterating.